# JavaScript - img name onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

How do I have JavaScript telling me the current image name with an ONCLICK event... and I need to do this with alert() for some reasons.

```
function imgName() {
    window.alert()
}
```

HTML

```
<figure>
        <img src="aster.jpg" alt="aster" onclick="window.alert()">
        <figcaption><span>I am aster</span></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving an id to image for query from js code.

and just writing:

```
alert(document.querySelector('#imageId').alt) //supposed alt as name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
onclick="window.alert()"
```

to:

```
onclick="imgName(this)"
```

and within your `imgName` function change:

```
window.alert()
```

to

```
alert(foo.src)
```

where `foo` is the argument you pass to the function via `function imgName(foo)`

```js
function imgName(foo) {
    alert(foo.src)
}
```

```html
<figure>
        <img src="aster.jpg" alt="aster" onclick="imgName(this)">
        <figcaption><span>I am aster</span></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Or you could just ditch the function and alert the src directly via:

```
<figure>
        <img src="aster.jpg" alt="aster" onclick="alert(this.src)">
        <figcaption><span>I am aster</span></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below -

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <script language="javascript" >

   function imgName() {
   var fullPath = document.getElementById("img1").src;
    window.alert(fullPath)
  }

  </script>

  <img src="aster.jpg" alt="aster" id="img1" onClick="imgName()">

  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In "onclick" you are not calling the function "imgName()".
Do this:

```
<figure>
    <img src="aster.jpg" alt="aster" onclick="imgName()">
    <figcaption><span>I am aster</span></figcaption>
</figure>
```

If "current image name" means that you want the alt attribute ("aster"), the code of function need to be this:

```
function imgName() {
  var nameOfPics = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("alt");
  alert(nameOfPics);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want.. I want the attribute. The console is saying:

Uncaught ReferenceError: imgName is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onclick

Comment: Try to declare the function before its use, for example before the closing tag of the head.
<script>function imgName(){
var nameOfPics = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].getAttribute("alt"); alert(nameOfPics);
}</script></head>

Answer (score 0):

The problems is when you click the image, you didn't call the related function.

Change `onclick="window.alert()"` with the related function to return window alert.

```
<img src="aster.jpg" alt="aster" onclick="window.alert()">
```

Change with :

```
<img src="aster.jpg" alt="aster" onclick="imgName()">
```

I Hope its can help you, pardon me if this is not the best answer